# how to allocate NSTimer property from another class in my class

Tags: objective-c, xcode, properties, nstimer

I have two class. I have one property `NSTimer` in my first class like this:

```
@interface KKProgressTimer : UIView

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSTimer *TimeCount;

@end
```

I could create two object from `KKProgressTimer` class and add in my second class.

in my second class I want to allocate `NSTimer` property to every object `KKProgressTimer` class.but I can't please guide me!!!

```
//this loop check and get two object KKProgressTimer class
for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[KKProgressTimer class]]) {

            KKProgressTimer *Progress = (KKProgressTimer*)subview;
            //now I want to allocate NSTimer property this here and define scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval for it

            //timing = [[NSTimer alloc]init];
            //timing = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(CountDown:) userInfo:timing repeats:YES];

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend maybe you forget set method for TimeCount.

write this code in second class:

```
Progress.TimeCount = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(CountDown:) userInfo:timing repeats:YES];
```

and write this code in .m file `KKProgressTimer class`

```
- (void)setTimeCount:(NSTimer *)TimeCount {
    if (TimeCount) {
        TimeCount = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: But if he really has it as a synthesized property, there should be a `setTimeCount` created automatically for him.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably create a method inside `KKProgressTimer` to start up its own timer and handle its own callbacks but if you want to do it from outside, try:

```
Progress.TimeCount = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(CountDown:) userInfo:timing repeats:YES];
```

Note, however that this means the object that contains the loop is going to get all the timer callbacks for both subviews.

Comment: -[KKProgressTimer setTimeCount:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x796bd680
2014-09-29 16:22:30.956 MetroMVC[10440:315833] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[KKProgressTimer setTimeCount:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x796bd680'

Comment: Try changing the name of your property from `TimeCount` to `timeCount`. The capital letter is non-standard and may be confusing it. (And don't forget to change `Progress.TimeCount` to `Progress.timeCount` too!)

Comment: I'm becoming less convinced that capital letters are the problem.  Are you sure that's the exact interface for `KKProgressTimer`?  Is the property synthesized?  (What does the compiler say if you use `[Progress setTimeCount:[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(CountDown:) userInfo:timing repeats:YES]];` instead?)